# How do I create CommonJS module that span across multiple files?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I am writing a NodeJS app and I would like to separate my classes into separate files, but have namespaces (modules) with many classes inside them, using one file for one class.

As I understand, CommonJS, which is used by NodeJS to `require` objects in other files, treat every file as a different module.

In that light, how do I create CommonJS module that span across multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Your namemespace/grouping module may look this (eager require):

**customer.js**:

```
module.exports.wholesale = require('./customers/wholesale');
module.exports.retail = require('./customers/retail');
module.exports.special = require('./customers/special');
```

And now when you need clients module, you could write:

```
var Customer = require('customer.js');
```

and you have access to all customer types:

```
var wholesale = Customer.wholesale;
var retail = Customer.retail;
var special = Customer.special;
```

In this solution when you import Customer, it load all submodules too. Sometimes submodules may be very big and you only need one submodule. if yes you could write grouping customer module like this (lazy require):

```
module.exports.wholesale = function(){
  return require('./customers/wholesale');
}
module.exports.retail = function(){
  return require('./customers/retail');
}
module.exports.special = function(){
  return require('./customers/special');
}
```

and you have access to all customer types:

```
var wholesale = Customer.wholesale();
var retail = Customer.retail();
var special = Customer.special();
```

You could make more deeper nesting, by grouping other grouping modules.